# Coordinate free generalizations of vector identities

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curvilinear-coordinates

For the common vector identities (for example, those listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Summary_of_important_identities)), how is it proven that these are coordinate free formulae (at least in the sense of curvilinear coordinates)?

Most common proofs show the identities hold in a Cartesian coordinate system, however is this general enough to prove that they are also true for arbitrary curvilinear coordinates? Is it sufficient to say that since div, grad and curl have more general geometric definitions (that are coordinate free), if an identity is proven in a Cartesian basis it generalizes to all curvilinear coordinates? Is it something to do with classical vector calculus dealing with $\mathbb{R}^3$, for which there is already a Euclidean coordinate system and the cross-product?

Comment: All those identities make no mention of coordinates.

Comment: @Mason Sure, but how is it proven that they are coordinate free?

Comment: What do you mean by coordinate free? You don't need coordinates to interpret any of the identities.

Comment: @Mason how can the identities be proven in general curvilinear coordinates?

Comment: You asked "Is it sufficient to say that since div, grad and curl have more general geometric definitions (that are coordinate free), if an identity is proven in a Cartesian basis it generalizes to all curvilinear coordinates?" and the answer is "Yes." for **precisely** the reason that you give.

Comment: What does it mean to prove an identity in general curvilinear coordinates? It seems like you want to prove a different identity altogether.

Comment: To which curvilinear coordinates are you thinking ?

Comment: @Mason say, how would one prove the identity $\nabla \times (\mathbf a\times \mathbf b) = \mathbf a\nabla \cdot \mathbf  b + \mathbf  b \cdot \nabla \mathbf  a - \mathbf  b \nabla \cdot \mathbf  a - \mathbf a \cdot \nabla \mathbf  b$? I know you can prove it in Cartesian coordinates, but then how does that prove it also holds in cylindrical and spherical coordinates, for example?

Comment: @JeanMarie see above comment, if that helps. Sorry if I still don't make sense

Comment: @user246795 What do you mean by it holding in cylindrical coordinates? The coordinates you choose don't change the definitions of $\nabla$, $+$, $-$, $\cdot$, etc. Unless your coordinates come with an implicit change in the definitions of the above operations, then there is nothing to show.

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates).